# Skip loop conditionally in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have a time based template :

```
{{hourly}}
    <li class='time' {{#if time}} {{timeHour time @index}} ... > </li>
{{/hourly}}
```

And JS :

```
helpers.timeHour = function(epochTime, index) {

   .
   .
 if(epochTime < currentEpochTime) {
     // SKIP LOOP - Go to Next loop value for Time
 }
```

I want to skip the loop if epoch time is less than current time and go to display next epoch time. How to skip the loop for this iteration? 
Returning "", sends and displays empty li value

Comment: Use a `break;` statement

Comment: Break will break the loop... i need to continue with the loop with the next iteration...just skip that index conditionally

Comment: Use `continue;` then

Comment: Where is the loop?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `break;` to break the iteration loop or a 'continue;' to skip the current iteration

```
helpers.timeHour = function(epochTime, index) {

while(epochTime < currentEpochTime) {
 // SKIP LOOP - Go to Next loop value for Time
 continue;
}
```

Comment: Did not work... Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement

Comment: `continue;` must be inside a `for` loop , try `return false;`